# Extract all font nodes from pasted data

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I can extract the content of the pasted data in javascript. I want to extract all the font nodes in that pasted data.

By using `document.getElementsByTagName('font')` extract all the font nodes from within the whole container. But I want to extract only from the pasted data, so that I can change the font face to "Open Sans". In detail:

I have a contentEditable div container, i.e.

```
 <div id="content" contenteditable="true">
```

I have added

```
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener("paste", onPaste);
```

In the function

```
function onPaste(evt)
{
  var pastedData = evt.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
  var fontNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('font');
  for(var i=0; i<fontNodes.length; i++)
    {
      fontNodes[i].setAttribute('face', 'open sans');
    }
}
```

Result of this snippet: It extracts all the font nodes from the whole document and change it into open sans.

Expected result: What my requirement is extract all the font nodes from only the data which is to be pasted, and change the font nodes in it to open sans.

Somehow, when i do:

```
pastedData.getElementsByTagName('font');
```

I get an error. Please help.

Comment: Have no chance to test it right now, but I see that your for loop has a bug: you should use fontNodes.length .

Comment: Also the font tag is super deprecated. Better use cos for styling. But you might have a reason...

Answer (score 1):

`clipboardData.getData()` gives you a string.

There are no nodes until you parse that string into a DOM tree.

```js
function onPaste(evt) {
    var pastedData = evt.clipboardData.getData('text'),
        tempDiv = document.createElement('div'),
        fontNodes, i;

    tempDiv.innerHTML = pastedData;  // parsing happens here, NOW we have nodes

    fontNodes = tempDiv.getElementsByTagName('font');    
    for(i = 0; i < fontNodes.length; i++) {
        fontNodes[i].setAttribute('face', 'open sans');
    }

    pastedData = tempDiv.innerHTML;  // convert it back to string

    document.getElementById('target').textContent = pastedData;
}

document.getElementById('test').onpaste = onPaste;
```

```html
<textarea id="test" rows="6" cols="75" placeholder="Paste HTML here"></textarea>

<pre id="target"></pre>
```